# Can we exchange our good deeds in order to get something in this world?

Tags: dua, deeds

Can we exchange our good deeds in order to get something in this world? I saw many people that pray to Allah that "he can take my good deeds and in return he give my parents or friend longer life" will that dua effect his good deeds account?

Comment: Does this imply that those people already know if their good deeds have already being 'accepted' by Allah? Also IMO Allah is Gracious enough to double our deeds   when we invite others to good so God does not need our barter. He is All-Sufficient, All Powerful. When making a dua we should have 'Yakeen e Kaamil' that Allah will accept our duas. He does not need our good deeds or barter. It is we who are in need of Allah's mercy and grace.

Comment: In your Question you assume something we don't even know about: did Allah even accept any of our deeds or does this verse apply for us http://legacy.quran.com/25/23?

Comment: This is a Kind of ancient Hindu concept I have heard of!